# i want to display the latest price of assigned code from another sheet in google sheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a sheet along with this message. I want to display the latest price for the code which i already purchased earlier(in second sheet 'price history') lets assume that price shown in the topmost of the table is purchased first. so i want to know the latest price which come downwards using importrange. maybe displaying the price in descending order will help me out.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT({A2:B, ROW(A2:A)}, 3, 0), 99^99, 2, 1, 1), 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have dates in **column C** in **Sheet 2**

Try below formula:

**Formula in C2 in Sheet1**

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(vlookup(B2:B,sort(Sheet2!A2:C,Sheet2!A2:A,True,Sheet2!C2:C,False),2,0)))
```

[image]